# How to set default theme from code using the fyne GUI framework?

Tags: go, themes, fyne

I can run my Fyne application with `FYNE_THEME=light` to make it use a light background and running without this var it will default to `dark`. Is there a way to reverse this behaviour? Having the application start with the light theme by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the theme globally by running fyne_settings to change user theme.

```
go get fyne.io/fyne/cmd/fyne_settings
```

All fyne apps will respect the configuration set in that app.

If your intent is to override the user theme (be careful about doing this as their settings will be ignored) you can configure the app settings in code:

```
myApp.Settings().SetTheme(theme.LightTheme())
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand how this works. This wouldn't apply to users I redistribute my binary to, would it?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t code your personal preference into an application. If you override the default theme it will no longer respond to user preferences.

Comment: However if you wish to ignore user preference you can do so by calling ‘myApp.Settings().SetTheme(theme.LightTheme())’

Comment: Thank you. Can you add this to your answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

add

```golang
os.Setenv("FYNE_THEME", "light")
```

in `func main()` before you show and run the window.

App would start with light theme by default.